# What's the difference between @computed and @action in MobX?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

What's the difference between `@computed` and `@action` in MobX?

They both are functions, so what is difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@computed** is used when the function will 'compute' the return value from existing information.

**@action** is used for functions that will change to the existing information (state), and prompts 'observers' to access the latest version of the relevant 'observable(s)'.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is stated in the [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/api.html#computed).

action

> Usage: action(fn) or action (annotation)
>
> Use on functions that intend to modify the state.

computed

> Usage: computed(fn, options?) or computed(options?) (annotation)
>
> Creates an observable value that is derived from other observables,
> but won't be recomputed unless one of the underlying observables
> changes.

So computed doesn't do anything other than observing the state.
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/computed-3cjo9?file=/src/index.tsx)

action actually modify the state. [action example](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html)